# asp.net core, limit MaxRequestBodySize for each API call

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I like to set the MaxRequestBodySize for an API operation depending on a query string parameter when API operation is called.

Let's say, something like that:

```
    [HttpPost("{para1}")]
    [RequestSizeLimit(...when para1 = "a" ? 500MB : 50MB)]
    public void PostIt(string para1, [FromBody] string bodyContent)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
```

However, with the RequestSizeLimit attribute this cannot be done, I guess somhow with the middleware it should be possible, but I have to admit, have not found any working solution so far.

Is this technically even possible and how can I achieve the goal?

I'm using .net 6.0

Comment: If you need to do it dynamically, you need to do it with a middleware or similar like this: https://khalidabuhakmeh.com/increase-file-upload-limit-for-aspdotnet#generic-middleware-instructions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to set the MaxRequestBodySize for an API operation, using RequestSizeLimit is right choice. But usually argument should be numbers. For example, this following code would allow *PostIt* to accept request bodies up to
30,000,000bytes.

```
[HttpPost]                                     
[RequestSizeLimit(30_000_000)]                   
public void PostIt(string para1, [FromBody] string bodyContent)                        
{
```

I see you mentioned the middleware here, if the request is not working by an MVC action, the limit can still be modified by using the **IHttpMaxRequestBodySizeFeature**. For example:

```
app.Run(async context =>                                                               
{                                   
context.Features.Get<IHttpMaxRequestBodySizeFeature>().MaxRequestBodySize = 30_000_000;
```

Using the middleware or not, the argument should be a number. So I suggest writeing a function to finish your goal and then return a number as the argument.

Comment: Thanks! context.Features.Get<IHttpMaxRequestBodySizeFeature>().MaxRequestBodySize does the trick. I just have to set the limit according to some conditions done based on context. Cool!

Comment: Thank you for your mark! I'm glad my answer can help you!